# Wikipedia does not list insertion complexity for arrays - why?

Tags: data-structures, arrays

Wikipedia does not list insertion complexity for arrays in the [list of linked-list implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Tradeoffs).

Is this because insertion operations are not defined on the array ADT?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. I removed the second one (note that it's still available [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/57844/revisions)); please repost on its own -- if it's not already been answered [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/6980/98), [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29122/98) or [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/49056/98).

Comment: @Raphael - sorry, but your revisions to my question were too heavy-handed IMO.

Comment: The linked article contains specific values for insertion/deletion complexity in both dynamic and fixed-size arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is a fixed-size data structure, and insertions would change its size. Thus they are impossible, which is why Wikipedia says "N/A" for the insertion complexity.

A dynamic array *can* have its size changed, which is why complexities are given in that column.

Comment: "The array is a fixed-size data structure" - should this be ADT?